# Using FIRST_VALUE with condition based on another column

Tags: t-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have Snowflake as our Data warehouse but my question is related to any SQL dialect that supports window functions like FIRST_VALUE, LAST_VALUe, LEAD, LAG.

I have a table as followed.
[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcaMP.png)

What I want is to create another column, lets say PreferredCurrencyCurrent which should basically be the most recent value of PreferredCurrency from the records that have
EventName = AccountCreated or AccountUpdatedEvent2

So, the result should be like this

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzvbc.png)

I have tried using Window functions FIRST_VALUE, LEAD/LAG but have not managed to get it right with this additional condition of checking the EventName.

Answer (score 1):

I think the ANSI Standard way would be

```
FIRST_VALUE(PreferredCurrency) 
    FILTER(WHERE EventName IN ('AccountCreated', 'AccountUpdatedEvent2')) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY EventCreated DESC)
```

However, I don't know of any DBMS where this would actually work yet. I think Postgres is probably closest, but the `FILTER` clause is not yet implemented for non-aggregate window functions. For now, I think you'll have to make do with a co-related subquery:

```
SELECT *, 
        (   SELECT PreferredCurrency 
            FROM    T AS T2 
            WHERE   T2.AccountID = T.AccountID 
            AND     T2.EventName IN ('AccountCreated', 'AccountUpdatedEvent2') 
            AND     T2.EventCreated <= T.EventCreated 
            ORDER BY T2.EventCreated DESC 
            FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY -- or your DBMS Equivalent
        ) AS PreferredCurrencyCurrent
FROM    T
ORDER BY AccountKey DESC;
```

**[Example on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9df9052a51d91183037e9ebccf2d3dc1)**

Comment: Thanks @GarethD. Problem is I have 20 more such columns and co-related subquery could be a performance bottleneck and also our DW Snowflake does not support co-related subquery completely :(

Comment: Truly a knowledgeable practitioner here. Thank you.